# Session variable getting deleted

Tags: node.js, express, session, variables

I am using express-session to do session handling in my NodeJS app featuring an Express server.

I developed an API with certain endpoints to do things such as session handling, saving data that users post etc.

I originally made a mockup of my app with vanilla HTML/CSS/JS (what I was familiar with) to test the API. However, I later remade the front end with React, hitting all the same endpoints that I wrote with the initial vanilla app. However, when I try to save a variable to the express-session object with the React front end, the variable doesn't persist in `req.session`. For example, on a successful login attempt, I save a `user` variable containing the user's username to the `req.session`. This works fine, and if I log `req.session` to the console at this point, I see the variable within the object. However, if I then hit another endpoint, and try to access the`req.session.user` variable, it doesn't exist, although the `cookie` object stays in `req.session`.

What has me stumped, though, is that this problem only arises when I use the React app. When I hit the same endpoint using the front end that uses static HTML pages, I can access the `user` variable from `req.session` from any endpoint. This problem didn't arise when I was initially developing the app using static HTML pages with linked JS files doing AJAX calls to send/receive data.

The React app has no problems with sending or receiving data to/from the server, however the server code executes differently when invoked from the React app. Within the same instance of the Express app running, the two apps perform differently.

My code saving the `user` variable:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  username = req.body.username;
  password = req.body.password;
  queryString = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = "' + username + '";';
  connection.query(queryString, function (err, result) {
    if(result[0] == undefined){
      console.log("user doesn't exist");
    }
    else{
      var savedPass = result[0].password;
      var json = {}
      if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, savedPass)) {
        console.log("success!")
        req.session.user = username;
        json.response = "correct";
        console.log(req.session)
      }
      else{
        console.log('wrong pass, try again');
        json.response = "incorrect";
      }
    }

    res.send(json);
  });
})
```

The `console.log(req.session)` under the `if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, savedPass)) {` conditional outputs the following (desired) object:

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-12-10T01:25:45.023Z,
     originalMaxAge: 60000,
     httpOnly: false },
  user: 'fuckun' }
}
```

I try to receive it by doing a `console.log` of the `req.session` variable in another endpoint. In the vanilla app it shows me the same data as shown above, but when I am using the react app, it outputs the following:

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-12-10T01:25:48.499Z,
     originalMaxAge: 60000,
     httpOnly: false } }
```

This object is missing the `user` variable.

I'm at a loss for what's going on, I've been Googling around and trying to debug this problem for nearly a week. I t doesn't make sense to me why the server side code is performing differently when different clients hit the same endpoint.

Any help or information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the React app served by the same domain? If not does you server support CORS?

Comment: @Khang Same domain, different port. I added "app.set("trust proxy", 1);.

Either way, the data is properly getting sent and received to and from the server, the problem is what the server does after it gets the data. Thanks for the response.